# C++ stod rounding the doubles

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, double

In c++, std::stod(*string*) converts a string to a floating decimals. So, doing this

std::cout << std::stod("378760.58") << "\n";

I would expect it to print `378760.58` to stdout but it rounds up and prints `378761` instead. std::stod() sometimes works as expected but it sometimes acts weird in an unexpected way.

Can anyone explain why and what alternative I could use to convert from string to double in c++? thanks for all the responses :)

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the conversion to double. The stream inserter for doubles rounds to six digits by default, so that’s what you’re seeing. Read about [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Answer (score 1):

you can add "iomanip" head file and use the following code:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::stod("378760.58") << "\n";
```

Comment: @apix as suggested by a comment on your question and this answer, there's nothing wrong with your double.  The standard output just works that way, `strtod` has nothing to do with it.  See https://ideone.com/oRMQ7K for an example.